# Github Enterprize Private repo access

Tags: github, github-api, github-enterprise

How can I check the last commit date(update_at, pushed_at) of all the private repository that is under the Github Enterprize? I generated an access token giving myself all the rights still I am not able to access the private repo through API calls. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As documented in "[Scopes for OAuth Apps](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps)", a PAT (Personal Access Token) should be enough to lake those GitHub API work.

But you need to make sure said PAT does have the `repo` scope.

And use it like:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" https://api.github.com/...
```